# How to process all data from multiple XML files after merging using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSL to read in three XML documents which are identical except their attributes have  different values (potentially I will be reading many XML files).  I want to count the number of times the "outcome" attribute has a value "Passed" or "Failed" for the  element whose "testName" attribute = "TestOne".  I am achieving this using the following:

**File1.xml**

```
<container>
    <build>
        <Tests>
            <Results>
                <Result testName="TestOne" outcome="Passed" ></Result>
                <Result testName="TestTwo"  outcome="Passed" ></Result>
            </Results>
        </Tests>    
    </build>
</container>
```

**File2.xml**

```
<container>
    <build>
        <Tests>
            <Results>
                <Result testName="TestOne" outcome="Passed" ></Result>
                <Result testName="TestTwo"  outcome="Failed" ></Result>
            </Results>
        </Tests>    
    </build>
</container>
```

**File3.xml**

```
<container>
    <build>
        <Tests>
            <Results>
                <Result testName="TestOne" outcome="Failed" ></Result>
                <Result testName="TestTwo"  outcome="Failed" ></Result>
            </Results>
        </Tests>    
    </build>
</container>
```

**Index.xml**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge3.xsl"?>
<list>
    <entry name="File1.xml" />
    <entry name="File2.xml" />
    <entry name="File3.xml" />
</list>
```

**Merge2.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/list/entry">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/container/build/*[local-name()='Tests']" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Results']">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="'TestOne'" />
    <xsl:variable name="totalPassed" select="*[local-name()='Result'][@testName = 'TestOne'][@outcome = 'Passed']" />
    <xsl:variable name="totalFailed" select="*[local-name()='Result'][@testName = 'TestOne'][@outcome = 'Failed']" />

    <h2>Totals</h2>
    <table border="1" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="5" >
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Test Name</th>
            <th>Total Passed</th>
            <th>Total Failed</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count($totalPassed)"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count($totalFailed)"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result produces 3 Totals tables.  My intention is to display one Totals table displaying how many times TestOne has passed and failed in all the XML documents.
It seems each XML document is being read/selected and then processed one at a time.  I'd like to read in and select all the XML files before processing them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could gather *all* the `Result` elements from across the three documents using something like

```
<xsl:variable name="allResults"
  select="(/ | document('file2.xml') | document('file3.xml'))//Result" />
```

and then apply predicates to this to count the elements you're interested in, for example

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  count($allResults[@testName = 'TestOne'][@outcome = 'Failed'])" />
```

Instead of a fixed set of file names, if you have a main `index.xml` that lists all the files you want to combine, for example:

```
<list>
    <entry name="File1.xml" />
    <entry name="File2.xml" />
    <entry name="File3.xml" />
</list>
```

then you can use this index as the main input to your stylesheet and the `allResults` variable becomes:

```
<xsl:variable name="allResults"
  select="document(/list/entry/@name)//Result" />
```

When you pass a node set to the `document` function it takes the string value of each node in turn and treats that as the URI of a file to load, returning the resulting *set* of document root nodes.

Here's a complete example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:variable name="allResults"
    select="document(/list/entry/@name)//Result" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="'TestOne'" />

    <h2>Totals</h2>
    <table border="1" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="5" >
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Test Name</th>
            <th>Total Passed</th>
            <th>Total Failed</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count($allResults[@testName = $name]
                                              [@outcome = 'Passed'])"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count($allResults[@testName = $name]
                                              [@outcome = 'Failed'])"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A variation of the original question uses a file called "index.xml" containing references to all XML files to process (could be hundreds) with a modification to merge2.xsl.  How would one achieve the intended result with this new variation?

Comment: @user2734805 this is actually simpler than the case of fixed file names - see my edit.

Comment: Ian - Your example worked for me.  The concept of a "node set" was the piece I was missing.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2734805 glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left.  This lets others see at a glance that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same as above, but without a variable.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <h2>Totals</h2>
    <table border="1" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="5" >
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Test Name</th>
            <th>Total Passed</th>
            <th>Total Failed</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/list/entry">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(document(@name)/container/build/Tests/Results/Result[@outcome eq 'Passed'])"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(document(@name)/container/build/Tests/Results/Result[@outcome eq 'Failed'])"/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No, that will have the same effect as the original stylesheet in the question, producing a separate count for each file rather than a single aggregate count across all files.